# Bash, how to loop over all directories and command "ls"

Tags: bash, loops, directory

I think it's a fundamental question, but I don't know how to do it. What I want to do is that 
visiting all directories including all subdirectories below my home directory and command "ls" in every directories I found. Any tips? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How about `ls -R`? (For your home directory, `ls -R $HOME`)

Answer (score 0):

1. `find ~ -type d -exec ls \;`     Look underneath your home directory for all directories and run `ls`.
2. `ls -R`     Run `ls` recursively on all subdirectories of your home directory.